# ASP.NET show PDF file to user instead of "save as" dialog

Tags: asp.net, pdf

My ASP.NET application return PDF file to user using code below

```
Context.Response.Clear();
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Context.Response.TransmitFile(optionEntityCmd.PathToSave);
Context.Response.End();
```

This code show Save As browser dialog, is it possible instead of Save As dialog load PDF file directly in browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could append the [Content-Disposition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) header:

```
Context.Response.AppendHeader(
    "Content-Disposition", 
    "inline; filename=foo.pdf"
);
```

Comment: Yes, it is already added, I just missed it to post here

Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

Comment: Oops, sorry. You want it inline, not attachment. I misread your question. Please see my update.

Comment: I am trying to show PDF file in browser without saving the file. I am using ASP.NET MVC. Can you please let me know how did you solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260041/asp-net-mvc-generate-pdf-from-byte?noredirect=1#comment52422242_32260041

Answer (score 0):

Is it a dynamically created file? If not, you can just hyperlink or Response.Redirect to it I believe.

Comment: The file is stored on HDD but I do not want to host files URL storage on IIS, I want to hide actual file location so I use Context.Response.TransmitFile. I am not sure how your suggestion could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for sure for classic asp.net but using mvc, streaming it to the user does what you want:

```
MemoryStream stream = PDF.GeneratePDFByStream();
stream.Flush(); //Always catches me out
stream.Position = 0; //Not sure if this is required
return stream;
```

with

```
public static MemoryStream GeneratePDFByStream() {
    var doc1 = new Document();
    //use a variable to let my code fit across the page...
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "PDFs";
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, stream);
    writer.CloseStream = false;

    // Actual Writing
    doc1.Open();
    // writing comes here, you will probably just load the PDF in a stream?
    doc1.Close();

    return stream;
}
```

And your MVC controller returns something like

```
return File(GetPDFStream(id), "application/pdf");
```

So, I know this is not the exact answer you are looking for, but maybe you should try to *stream your PDF* to the user as it will open it in a new tab as far as I ever tested it.

From the top of my head, you should get something like:

```
Response.Clear(); 
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; 
Response.OutputStream.Write( objMemoryStream.ToArray(), 0,        
Convert.ToInt32(objMemoryStream.Length)); 
Response.Flush(); 
try { Response.End(); } catch{}
```