# File download option in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application [asp.net], i write a code for downloading, it is working fine, but at the time of downloading one window display "open"/ "save", i dont want to ask this message, when i click on download it should display the File. in a new window or in a new page. [The downloading page is excel]. can you help me. Than you. My code like this :

```
    string pah = "./Files/" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["targetname"].ToString();                     
        // You should put more appropriate MIME type as per your file time - perhaps based on extension
        Response.ContentType = "application/octate-stream";
        //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=[your file name w/o path]");
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["targetname"].ToString());
        // Start pushing file to user, IIS will do the streaming.
        Response.TransmitFile(pah);
        Response.Flush();
```

can you help me. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ASP donot have the handle on client side machine and so it cannot open the file directly with the associated application. For security purpose a good browser will always prompt the user for 'what you want to do with this file? open ? save to disk? cancel?". Still there may be some ActiveX way to do this in Microsoft IE, like there is a Microsoft Word ActiveX and browser plugin for other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This thread may help you:

- [ASP.NET show PDF file to user instead of "save as" dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861395/asp-net-show-pdf-file-to-user-instead-of-save-as-dialog)

You need to change "attachment;" to "inline;" in your Response header.

```
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename="+ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["targetname"].ToString());
        Response.TransmitFile(pah);
        Response.Flush();
```

If you still have same issue with Response.TransitFile, please use following method. Also make sure that Target File name has XLSX extension name:

```
// Open the file.
iStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open,  System.IO.FileAccess.Read,System.IO.FileShare.Read);

// Total bytes to read:
dataToRead = iStream.Length;

Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + +ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["targetname"].ToString());

// Read the bytes.
while (dataToRead > 0)
{
    // Verify that the client is connected.
    if (Response.IsClientConnected) 
    {
        // Read the data in buffer.
        length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);

        // Write the data to the current output stream.
        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

        // Flush the data to the HTML output.
        Response.Flush();

        buffer= new Byte[10000];
        dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
    }
    else
    {
        //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
        dataToRead = -1;
    }
}
```

But I really recommend use HTML-based file viewers such as :

- Google Docs
- https://sheet.zoho.com/excelviewer
- thinkfree.com

Comment: I update the above answer and add alternative way to TransitFile. I hope this helps.